# How to get as variable and display in html particular info from javascript console.log?

Tags: javascript, html, console.log

I have a task to get and display in html a particular data from API result (console.log). For now on, I only have a javascript that gets exchange rates with currency conversion. From fetched data I only need currency rate.

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("apikey", "r4T22n3O14QL7FoG6FzY7FuUHTNXiKAy");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'follow',
  headers: myHeaders
};

//var rslt = console.log(result);

fetch("https://api.apilayer.com/currency_data/convert?to=RUB&from=EUR&amount=1", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Here is the result I get in console.log
and my problem is that I cannot display : 1. **anything** from that log **to HTML** and 2. **particular data** (rates) **from** that **log**.

this is the console log I am getting:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "query": {
        "from": "EUR",
        "to": "RUB",
        "amount": 1
    },
    "info": {
        "timestamp": 1658378463,
        "quote": 56.217115
    },
    "result": 56.217115
}
```

I need to get a rates/"quote" as a variable in order to use it elsewhere.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show us how did you try to display this variables in HTML ?

Comment: So use `.json()` instead of `.text()` and access the property in the object.

Comment: okay , I am out of limits for requests 
can I get data from here ? 

api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=48e4e2e268e63ccf935d26ff10a921b8

let's say to get weather description

I need just a working example so I can figure out

Answer (score 1):

Use `response.json()` and then extract the properties that you want into variables.

```js
fetch("https://api.apilayer.com/currency_data/convert?to=RUB&from=EUR&amount=1", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    let quote = json.info.quote;
    document.getElementById("quote").innerText = quote;
   })
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Replace `"quote"` with the actual ID of the element where you want to show the quote.

Comment: thanks for response, but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I think I have a problem with request limits I reached

extra question, can I get particular data from here ?
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=48e4e2e268e63ccf935d26ff10a921b8

let's say to get weather description

Answer (score 0):

1. To display value using HTML, you need to use **Template literals** concept in javascript. You can set elements with a unique ID in HTML. Using HTML DOM Element innerHTML Property and Template Literals you can achieve.
2. Particular data (rates) from that log:

let rate = result.result;

As I mentioned above you will get the rate result.

Comment: honestly that could be more understandable if I have a working example

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like

```
<div id="quote"></div>
```

in your html,

I would do something like this:

```
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => { document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = data.info.quote})
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: thanks for your response , but this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer !

```
const render = data => {
      
      const rate = document.querySelector(".rate")
        rate.innerHTML = (data.info.rate).toFixed(2);
        

    }

    const init = url => {
      fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json()).then(render)
    }

    init("https://api.exchangerate.host/convert?from=EUR&to=RUB")
```

and of course this is another API provider, but anyway, this is the simplest way to get and manipulate with currency rate data.

Thanks for everyone's attempt :)